# In slack Block kit builder give color to list disc

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

[Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PxYY.png)

> Need to change that list discs color in block kit builder

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Color blocks are part of a legacy way of sending messages into Slack.  You can still use them but it's not recommended.  For more information, check out the documentation here: https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/attachments#fields